# NetSuite - Collecting information based on a given Saved Search ID

Tags: soap, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to test in Postman via NetSuite SOAP a way to enter a savedSearch ID and in return receive information from that saved search.

I tried sending a `POST` request to

```
https://<AccountID-SB2>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2021_1
```

with the below body:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2021_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:preferences>
            <platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>true</platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>
        </platformMsgs:preferences>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <platformMsgs:get>
            <platformMsgs:baseRef internalId="<SavedSearchID>" type="savedSearch" xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef"/>
        </platformMsgs:get>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but it keeps failing for me (I am getting 500 error message).

```
soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXException: savedSearch is not a legal value for {urn:types.core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}RecordTypepartners123.prod-ams-eu5.core.ns.internal
```

I tried changing my query but no matter what I do I get an error.

In my Headers I am using `SOAPAction` = `getSavedSearch`

Does anyone have an idea what I should change to get the info back?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, don't have time/knowledge to say more. But from what I understood, the saved search is not a record type, as it says, and you apparently tried to use it as one

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SOAP but a quick digging says that getSavedSearch returns a lists of Saved Searches Internal IDs. If you refer to [Advanced Searches in SOAP Web Services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3516862.html) and look at **How to Reference an Existing Saved Search**, it will show you a sample on how to use savedSearch with Internal ID. You can also look at SOAP code samples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3519853.html). There's a section for **Advanced Search Code Samples**